# Android actionLayout not showing with Toolbar

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I'm trying to show custom layout as an item in options menu.
And this is what I have done so far

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_profile"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I tried

```
    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_profile"
```

as well as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28891582/custom-layout-in-toolbar-not-showing) SO link but still it shows only title - Profile

I have created new project through Android Studio 1.5 with Blank Activity.
with minSDK = 15 and targetSDK = 23

Following is the code in Blank Activity.

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_profile);


    return true;
}
```

where am I going wrong ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35732788/1172181

Answer (score 66):

use `app:actionLayout` instead of `android:actionLayout`.

```
<item
   ...
   app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_profile"  
   app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Custom menu item is visible only when i set `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_profile"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="Profile"
android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_profile"
app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Just set the **showAsAction** elements to **always**

Comment: i just did that its not working, but when i added app:actionLayout instead of android:actionLayout it's working

Comment: That works, but what if I don't want to show it always?

Comment: you can use "ifRoom" instead of "always"

Answer (score 2):

Use "app:" instead of "android:"

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_profile"
```